# Runtime outdated, Game launcher outdated, On new dell inspiron15, Native log attached

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

```
Native Launcher Version: 19
Operating System: Windows 8.1
Application Hash: 703e21de391ba20ebee6fae3a694d0b7514febb5
Java Version: 
x64: 1
Starting download of: https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/launcher.json
Created pFile
Content length is 036E7C68
Got 200 from server
Download successful
Runtime outdated!
Runtime version should be should be 1.8.0_25
Game launcher outdated!
Hash should be 29e2e2ea1270cd7306a4d1fdb70dbb5db8aa9e8b
Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/jre/win-64/1.8.0_25/bdca00e1c2a1f2c23c9a77b65188b788d475a603/jre-win-64-1.8.0_25.lzma
Created pFile
Content length is 037830C8
Got 200 from server
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out
```

I have done all kinds of troubleshooting for this issue. minecraft has been downloaded and deleted 30-40 times since Christmas, the computer has been factory reset 4 times and a new operating system was installed, everything is up to date on the computer thanks to dell tech support. I am still having a problem running minecraft above is the native log, I have completed those steps but still nothing.... 
WHen minecraft is opened it says in the launcher long expected local files but not the correct size.

```
[15:25:20 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.6.5 (through bootstrap 4) started on windows...
[15:25:20 INFO]: Current time is Jan 8, 2015 3:25:20 PM
[15:25:20 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 8'
[15:25:20 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.2'
[15:25:20 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
[15:25:20 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_25'
[15:25:20 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
[15:25:20 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'
[15:25:20 INFO]: proxy == DIRECT
[15:25:20 INFO]: JFX is already initialized
[15:25:21 INFO]: Refreshing local version list...
[15:25:21 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list...
[15:25:24 INFO]: Refresh complete.
[15:25:24 INFO]: Loaded 1 profile(s); selected 'rmcrm12'
[15:25:24 INFO]: Refreshing auth...
[15:25:24 INFO]: Logging in with access token
[15:25:28 INFO]: Getting syncinfo for selected version
[15:25:28 INFO]: Queueing library & version downloads
[15:25:29 INFO]: Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (16 threads, 31 files)
[15:25:29 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[15:25:29 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.1\lwjgl-2.9.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[15:25:29 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
[15:25:29 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
\101e3535d3f482acb6d1d0259d53d12b25979788 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:48 WARN]: Couldn't download http://resources.download.minecraft.net/56/5680749048457f5772ec95a73d856ad792fa1717 for job 'Resources'
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3322) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3315) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.MonitoringInputStream.read(MonitoringInputStream.java:28) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.5]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.copyAndDigest(Downloadable.java:140) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.5]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.assets.AssetDownloadable.download(AssetDownloadable.java:104) ~[launcher.jar:1.6.5]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:109) [launcher.jar:1.6.5]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:1.6.5]
    at com.mojang.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:86) [launcher.jar:1.6.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_25]
[15:26:48 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\1c\1c3e5d6ccda1ebf90bd3cbdbfb385fb43601d464 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:51 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\10\101e3535d3f482acb6d1d0259d53d12b25979788 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:51 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\a7\a7d757b683fe02a372025b3ad592241b73d0c8f5 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:53 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\a7\a7d757b683fe02a372025b3ad592241b73d0c8f5 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:53 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\a3\a342f566600caf73464323b20b7770b5b9b7893a for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:53 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\1c\1c3e5d6ccda1ebf90bd3cbdbfb385fb43601d464 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:53 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\33\33acf13c25f65a432348e9476eda67d6a34831e3 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:53 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\a3\a342f566600caf73464323b20b7770b5b9b7893a for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:53 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\65\65b49739d48ebc47879ca5528c8283329980b304 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:55 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\65\65b49739d48ebc47879ca5528c8283329980b304 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:55 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\46\4609ec723b4e724f44c653b82de40ec159d2eea1 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:55 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\33\33acf13c25f65a432348e9476eda67d6a34831e3 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:55 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\9d\9d2202fce7908dcc5b5c8758c5cd517d863d4dd3 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\9d\9d2202fce7908dcc5b5c8758c5cd517d863d4dd3 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:59 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\e8\e89ef25ae1fa8c571a001b686d1f4eeda25e5cde for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:26:59 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\46\4609ec723b4e724f44c653b82de40ec159d2eea1 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:26:59 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\ae\aedeb53dd3315f964ff4d10d0003e4c5f41d1bb0 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:27:02 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\ae\aedeb53dd3315f964ff4d10d0003e4c5f41d1bb0 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:27:02 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\92\9272aef9f27dfcc10b6e3879b7a2a67f8faa1a83 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:27:02 WARN]: Had local file but it was the wrong size... had 61320 but expected 65328
[15:27:03 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\e8\e89ef25ae1fa8c571a001b686d1f4eeda25e5cde for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:27:03 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\d1\d14112bd7351ef48f193aa27b4517d4b0960f7b1 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:27:05 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\d1\d14112bd7351ef48f193aa27b4517d4b0960f7b1 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:27:05 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\47\47ad81223bcec870206484cd4d1a6202871df331 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:27:06 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\47\47ad81223bcec870206484cd4d1a6202871df331 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:27:06 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\c9\c9ac72409cbe6093e84d72a2a5c719d9e4a0e6b2 for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:27:07 INFO]: Finished downloading C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\c9\c9ac72409cbe6093e84d72a2a5c719d9e4a0e6b2 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[15:27:07 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\44\44380f86e13a06b1f0c6feec2d6644b67e6c4d9c for job 'Resources'... (try 0)
[15:27:07 INFO]: Making directory C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\44
```

Comment: From what I can tell, the download is timing out.  Are you downloading this at home?

Comment: yes, I have it hooked to the Ethernet cord. if you scroll up you will see where it says had local file but wasn't the size expected, it only timed out after hours of saying the local file wasn't the right size

Comment: C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\51\515d2dc1517b1907c72a79e758ef995a3b54aab1 for job 'Resources': Downloaded asset and hash matched successfully
[21:37:13 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Minecraft\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\objects\ee\ee4232cbe10c23b9aff88e9134dc0ae15a449de2 for job 'Resources'... (try 1)
[21:37:13 WARN]: Had local file but it was the wrong size... had 5840 but expected 92381
[21:37:18 WARN]: Couldn't download

Comment: That's...nowhere in your question.  If you have more information to add, I'd recommend editing it into your question.  The more you provide, the better the chance we can help you.

Comment: I tried putting it in with my question but im only allowed to put two links in my question, what I posted in my comment was from the launcher log

Comment: the last line of  my question says the problem about having the local file but it was the wrong size, that's the issue ive had since Christmas, the native log I just found and thought id see if I could get help with that and the launcher log problem, I know nothing about this stuff I am trying to download minecraft to a new computer for my grandson and have been having problems since Christmas day

Comment: What happens if you try going to `http://resources.download.minecraft.net` in your web browser?  Do you get a timeout, a 404, or something else?

Comment: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>E22DB16A86D6D1A9</RequestId>
<HostId>
pzR8VIUR67b3F1E9YwRTbYdjFQj/KGiCd7HrMnWcXryJ/SOfoG8T297FZ51E6vovmIoJbmY/k2M=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: I tried it a second time after I deleted minecraft and installed it again I got Http 403 Forbidden

Comment: If you're getting a 403 Forbidden, where are you?  Sounds like you're at school or university or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is trying many times, over and over again without progress. Update your outdated runtime or with the Minecraft updater if you *haven't* already.

• Download the runtime here: http://bit.ly/DownloadJRE

• Minecraft Updater will also update runtimes. It should start normally.

Hope this helps a *bit*.

Comment: Man, this was asked in 2015...

Comment: Man this was a comment from 3 months ago